Is a conditional compilation directive needed to ensure editor script is not compiled into build?
Should an editor script contain #if UNITY_EDITOR to get excluded from build for Android and iOS?
If so, where it should be written:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class WindowEditor : EditorWindow
{

    static float windowWidth = 1000f;
    static float windowHeight = 546f;

    [MenuItem("Window/New Window")]
    public static void OpenWindow()
    {
        WindowEditor wnd = GetWindow<WindowEditor>();
        wnd.titleContent = new GUIContent("New Window");
        wnd.minSize = new Vector2(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }
}


No directive is necessary; if you put this script in a folder called "Editor", or any sub-folder of such a folder, it will be skipped when compiling the game for all platforms.
Alternatively, you can put the directive at the top and bottom of the file, framing the whole code. This way, all the code gets ignored during a build, as though the file were completely empty:
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class WindowEditor : EditorWindow
{

    static float windowWidth = 1000f;
    static float windowHeight = 546f;

    [MenuItem("Window/New Window")]
    public static void OpenWindow()
    {
        WindowEditor wnd = GetWindow<WindowEditor>();
        wnd.titleContent = new GUIContent("New Window");
        wnd.minSize = new Vector2(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }
}
#endif

But this is more work and less efficient than just putting editor-only content and scripts in an Editor folder, where the compiler can skip opening or parsing them at all.

What if I didn't put the editor script in folder called "Editor"?

Is there any reason you wouldn't? You can always move it to such a folder if you didn't create it in one in the first place.

So any file (like my custom window sprites or it's visual tree asset) that is in Editor folder get excluded from build by default? and what if there is a Resources folder in Editor folder (I need it to load the sprites for another editor script)?

That sounds like a new question. Have you considered using EditorGUIUtility.Load instead of Resources.Load for this purpose to avoid any confusion between runtime resources and editor resources?

The script will also be ignored for builds if it is in a subfolder of a folder called "Editor", such as /Editor/CustomWindows/.

@Kevin is that also work but if the Editor if the Editor was the subfolder like Assets/My CustomWindow/Editor without adding a directive?

@AhmedDyaa If any directory in the script's path is named "Editor", the script is treated as Editor-only. So any of these: Assets/Editor/MyCustomWindow/, Assets/MyCustomWindow/Editor/, Assets/MyCustomWindow/Editor/Scripts/, Assets/Scripts/Editor/MyCustomWindow/, etc.
However, this would not be treated as Editor only (without adding a directive): Assets/MyCustomEditorWindow/.

@Kevin I apologize for my many questions, but for example, if the UXML file is in Assets/MyCustomWindow/Editor/Window Files/, which method do you prefer for me to upload it to the window editor script? Of course I can't use EditorGUIUtility.Load becasue it only load from Assets/Editor Default Resources/ + path is that right?

That sounds like something to post as its own question "How to load / where to put resources used by a custom editor window". I'd recommend posting that as its own stand-alone question instead of trying to fit an extended discussion into a comment thread.
